Deck Covering where it became brownish due to heat
Deck Covering
Hello Everyone,
I was hoping to get some opinion and directions. My deck started ‘browning’ few days ago and we think it is due to the sunlight. I am not even sure what type of material the deck covering is and was hoping to see if we can get rid of the brown stains or probably get a new deck covering.
Any input is much appreciated!!
Picture of deck:

what picture? ..

Sunlight usually causes fading of colour.  Depending on the material(plastic type), sunlight plus high temps might cause it, in which case usually replacement/covering.  Adding a picture again will help, plus having an idea of the material.  Wood with stain/paint would be easier to repair than a composite.
